# create new columns to arrange values that corresponding to another repeated value in another column to be in a single row

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame similar to this example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh8Nw.png)

and I want obtain new dataframe as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyCpd.png)

update:2

```
import pyspark.sql.types as typ
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *




labels=[('name', typ.StringType()),('month', typ.StringType()),('degree',typ.FloatType())]

schema=typ.StructType([typ.StructField(e[0],e[1],True) for e in labels])

degree_df = spark.read.csv("file:///home/Ahmad/ahmad_tst/TEST.csv", header= False,schema=schema)
table_count_c= degree_df.stat.crosstab("name","month").withColumnRenamed('name_month','name')

table_count_d=degree_df.groupBy("name","month").agg((min("degree")),(max("degree")))

 table_count_d.show()
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+
| name|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+
|Ahmad|  May|       38.0|       38.0|
|Ahmad|April|       40.0|       49.0|
| Emma|  May|       45.0|       50.0|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+



table_count_c= degree_df.stat.crosstab("name","month").withColumnRenamed('name_month','name')

 table_count_c.show()
+-----+-----+---+
| name|April|May|
+-----+-----+---+
|Ahmad|    2|  1|
| Emma|    0|  2|
+-----+-----+---+

table_4c= table_count_c.join(table_count_d, "name" , 'left_outer')

   table_4c.show()
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+
| name|April|May|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+
|Ahmad|    2|  1|April|       40.0|       49.0|
|Ahmad|    2|  1|  May|       38.0|       38.0|
| Emma|    0|  2|  May|       45.0|       50.0|
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Update :3

According to the following recommendation   " `you could get something similar to what you're after by performing left outer join on table_count_d with itself`"

the resulting data frame as given below;
[image]

I want to obtain dataframe as follows:

```
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| name|April|May|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+
|Ahmad|    2|  1|  May|       38.0|       38.0|April|       40.0|       49.0|
| Emma|    0|  2|  May|       45.0|       50.0|April|       00.0|       00.0|
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to do this with PySpark 2.0.1

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! What have you tried so far? did you look into the documentation? where did you get stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have any Idea after this updates

Comment: Thanks for the update. However to maximize the chances of getting help from the community, I would advise to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and also to consider editing the title to reflect what you're really after (I would have helped with that, but unsure what's the goal - are you trying to generate a different set of columns per  month?)

Comment: Anyway, you could get something similar to what you're after by performing left outer join on table_count_d with itself

Comment: Thank you for your idea but it didn't give the required result. thanks again for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.types as typ
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame



labels=[('name', typ.StringType()),('month', typ.StringType()),('degree',typ.FloatType())]

schema=typ.StructType([typ.StructField(e[0],e[1],True) for e in labels])

degree_df = spark.read.csv("file:///home/Ahmad/ahmad_tst/TEST.csv", header= False,schema=schema)

table_count_d=degree_df.groupBy("name","month").agg((min("degree")),(max("degree")))

table_count_c= degree_df.stat.crosstab("name","month").withColumnRenamed('name_month','name')

table1=table_count_c.join(table_count_d, "name" , 'left_outer')
df1 = table1.groupby('name').pivot('month').agg(fn.first('min(degree)'),fn.first('min(degree)'))
df1.show()
```

the resulting DF as follows :

```
+-----+-----+---+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| name|April|May|April_first(`min(degree)`, false)|April_first(`max(degree)`, false)|May_first(`min(degree)`, false)|May_first(`max(degree)`, false)|
+-----+-----+---+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|Ahmad|    2|  1|                             40.0|                             49.0|                           38.0|                           38.0|
| Emma|    0|  2|                             null|                             null|                           45.0|                           50.0|
+-----+-----+---+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

After that, you can rename columns as you like

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options; the first is slightly more elegant (especially if you have more than two months), but does not yield exactly what you're after; the second does generate it, but is more verbose. (it would help if you explicitly describe the logic of what you're trying to achieve).

**1. Use left outer join**

The idea is as suggested above, with a condition on a unique id column to prevent the same pair from appearing twice.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = sql_sc.createDataFrame([("Ahmad", "May", '38.0', '38.0'), ("Ahmad", "April", '40.0', '49.0'), ("Emma", "May", '45.0', '50.0')], 
                         ("name", "month", "min(degree)", "max(degree)"))

# add a unique id column
df1 = df1.withColumn('id', func.monotonically_increasing_id())

#self join - rename columns to maintain unique column name
df2 = df1
for c in df2.columns:
    df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed(c, c + '_2')

# use the id column to prevent the same pair from appearing twice
dfx = df1.join(df2, (df1['name'] == df2['name_2']) & (df1['month'] != df2['month_2']) & (df1['id'] < df2['id_2']) , 'left_outer' )
dfx.show()
```

Which yields:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| name|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|         id|name_2|month_2|min(degree)_2|max(degree)_2|       id_2|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|Ahmad|  May|       38.0|       38.0|17179869184| Ahmad|  April|         40.0|         49.0|42949672960|
|Ahmad|April|       40.0|       49.0|42949672960|  null|   null|         null|         null|       null|
| Emma|  May|       45.0|       50.0|60129542144|  null|   null|         null|         null|       null|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**2. Split data per month**

```
df_4 = df1.where(func.col('month') == 'April')
df_5 = df1.where(func.col('month') == 'May')

df_5.join(df_4, df_5['name'] == df_4['name'], 'outer').show()
```

Yielding:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| name|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|         id| name|month|min(degree)|max(degree)|         id|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|Ahmad|  May|       38.0|       38.0|17179869184|Ahmad|April|       40.0|       49.0|42949672960|
| Emma|  May|       45.0|       50.0|60129542144| null| null|       null|       null|       null|
+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Great! You may want to post and accept your own solution, so that others may be able to use your method.